# Laravel 5.5: Get Model without knowing app structure?

Tags: php, eloquent, schema, laravel-5.5

I'm developing a package. There are times when I need to interact with a User object. For some instance I can go through the `Auth::user()`; however, for others, I need the class name. For example, `App\User`, if you're using the base model.

Right now I use the package's `config` file to do this. Basically, you `$ php artisan vendor:publish` the package and set the class name there, if it is not the default `App\User`.

I'm curious if there's another way?

Like through the table name or something similar.

Note: Admittedly right now I'm stretching the boundaries of my Laravel knowledge; so, apologies if this is dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, I suppose read Laravel's own configuration, found in the `config/auth.php` file, assuming that the user is using the relevant defaults.

You could read it using:

```
config('auth.providers.users.model');
```

If a user wants to change the default model class name, this is where they would typically change it for Laravel's authentication system to work out of the box. So I would try there first.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thank you! Totally forgot about the existence of that configuration - despite having used it myself. ;)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. We all do things like that now and again! :]